# Validation of referenced value coming from client-side app

Tags: database-design, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongodb and trying to find a solution to create data priorly for users to select and use only one query per interface (one for user's selection interface and another is to show selected data). What I come up with is creating two collections: one for the data that can be selected and the other to store selected data. Let's say countries and cities as an example. I have one country collection which is like:

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    cities: [{
        name: { type: String }
    }]
}
```

One will input country and city data using this collection. When user creates a profile he/she will be able to select only these values using a select box. Then It will be saved in another collection:

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    surname: { type: String },
    addresses: [{
        country: { type: String },
        city: { type: String },
        description { type: String }
    }]
}
```

Now the question that came to mind is how could I ensure that a malicious user can not send a different country or city name and make the data inconsistent. I want to be able to update country and city names with users' address data. And I also wonder that is it a proper way or an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

## Use an enum

```
var cities = ['LA', 'New York', 'Washington', 'Orlando']

var s = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    cities: [{
        name: { type: String, enum: cities }
    }]
})


var personSchema = {
    name: { type: String },
    surname: { type: String },
    addresses: [{
        country: { type: String },
        city: { type: String, enum: cities },
        description { type: String }
    }]
}
```

[Check mongoose enum documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum)

Comment: I am aware of enum but it is not a solution. What if superuser want to add a new country with a set of cities? It should be stored at database right? But how? What is the proper way of doing it? @SantiagoQuinteros